# retrieve database values and then replace values with images outside of database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I cannot get my head around how to do this. 
I have a mysql table called 'companies' that has a column called 'language'. This language column contains country abbreviations (en, de, es...).

Then I have flags saved in media/images/flags (en.png, de.png, es.png...).

I do not want to save the flags in db but I want to change db-country abbrevs. into flags inside the code. Below, I store the country abbrevs from db inside abbrevs. and try somehow to match them to array keys.

Model (platform_model):

```
    public function get_country(){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT language FROM companies");
        return $query;
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public function set_flag(){
    $this->load->model('platform_model');
    $abbrevs = $this->platform_model->get_country();

    $flags = array(
        'de' => base_url('media/images/flags/de.png'),
        'en' => base_url('media/images/flags/en.png'),
        'it' => base_url('media/images/flags/it.png'),
        'fr' => base_url('media/images/flags/fr.png'),
        'es' => base_url('media/images/flags/fr.png'),
        'pt' => base_url('media/images/flags/pt.png'),
        'ru' => base_url('media/images/flags/ru.png'),
        'ch' => base_url('media/images/flags/ch.png'),
        'ja' => base_url('media/images/flags/ja.png')
    );

    //how can I compare/replace them from here?
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than array you can do something like..

```
<img src="media/images/flags/<? echo $county; ?>.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_replace`, get the search elements which are the country codes (keys) and the replacement values which are the flags (values)

```
$replace = array_values($flags);
$search = array_keys($flags);

$string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = func_get_args();
$num = func_num_args();

$keys = array();
$i = 0;
for($i=0;$i<$num;++$i){
    $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($arr[$i]));
}
$keys = array_unique($keys);

$merged = array();

foreach($keys as $key){
    $merged[$key] = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$num;++$i){
        $merged[$key][] = isset($arr[$i][$key])?$arr[$i][$key]:null;
    }
}
```